# Why "picker.delegate = self necessary"?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I am creating a simple camera app.

In the code, UIImagePickerControllerclass is the delegate of ViewControllerClass instance.

But why "picker.delegate = self"is necessary in this code?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBAction func launchCamera(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        let camera = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(camera) {
            let picker = UIImagePickerController()
            picker.sourceType = camera
            picker.delegate = self
            self.present(picker, animated: true)
    }
}

        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

            let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
            self.imageView.image = image
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
            self.dismiss(animated:  true)
        }
```

Comment: ya its manodatry, if you want to aceess the delegate then you need to mention `picker.delegate = self in current class

Comment: @risa8. when you set "picker.delegate = self" .your controller is use all delegate method of  UIImagePickerControllerDelegate. Control is given to your controller means delegation is transfer to your controller.

Comment: yes you have to

Comment: Why cant ViewController access the method of UIImagePickerControllerDelegate or UINavigationControllerDelegate by itself? I mean without UIImagePickerController.

Answer (score 0):

delegate of UIImagePickerController includes UIImagePickerControllerDelegate and UINavigationControllerDelegate.

UIImagePickerControllerDelegate for catch users' action about **take photo** or **choose picture**. 
UINavigationControllerDelegate for view controller navigation between **album and photo**